# jQuery .ajax() POST Only checkboxes :checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am getting an error in my .ajax() function when attempting to pass in the checkboxes

Here is the code:

```
if(typeof($post) !== 'undefined'){
    var $fname = $($post).attr('name').toString();
    var data = {$fname : []};
    alert($post);
    alert($fname);
    $($post + ":checked").each(function() {
        data[$fname].push($(this).val());
    });
}else{
    var data = null;    
}
```

The error I am getting in firebug is: `data[$fname].push($(this).val()); is undefined`

`$post` is just a class name passed into the function.. in this case it's `.del-checked`

The alerts sucessfully alert me the class name, and the checkbox name... in this case it's `del[]`

How can I get this to work in order to pass it to the `data` option of `$.ajax`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 `.del-checked`

Comment: Why don’t you just use `.serialize` instead of trying to cobble the dataset together yourself …?

Comment: @putvande I meant in terms of string and objects :-) just for the part `$($post + ":checked")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can not use a variable as a key when creating a new object

```
var data = {$fname : []};
```

is the same thing as doing

```
var data = {"$fname" : []};
```

You need to create the object and add the key with brackets

```
var data = {};
data[$fname] = [];
```

Comment: is there a limit on how many this array can hold?  I'm attempting to create a 'Check All' and delete, but am noticing that the delete functionality only receives 999 items?

Comment: Array can hold a lot more than that, look at what is being sent up in the post request in the dev tools.

Comment: firebug is showing only 1000 items (0 based array of course) is being posted: EDIT... sorry it's showing all 4800 items, so my issue is elsewhere... thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can't use variables as keys *unless* you use bracket notation

```
if (typeof($post) !== 'undefined'){

    var $fname = $($post).attr('name');
    var data = {};

    data[$fname] = [];

    $($post).filter(":checked").each(function() {
        data[$fname].push( this.value );
    });

}else{

    var data = null;    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var data = $($fname).serialize();
```